# how to access input value in function that are located at global scope

Tags: javascript, input, scope

```
let value1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
function display(){
 console.log(value1);
 }


display() // value1 (wanted this result)
```

it seems that input value only exist in the scope where it is been declared , how to utilise value1 in function when it is in global scope ?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Everything only exists in the scope where it was declared.  If something is declared in global scope, it's available inside any function (as long as it isn't shadowed by another declaration).  What exactly isn't working here?  Please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate and explain the problem.

Comment: value1 is input value  , I can't access it when I declare at global scope , always return empty string (not undefined nor any error ) . But if I put it in function , It then  can be access .

Answer (score 0):

Whatever declared in global scope can be accessed in function. For example:

```
    let value1 = 1;
    function display(){
      console.log(value1);
    }
    display() // console will display '1'
```

If you are trying to get a value from a HTML , do you mean:

```
    document.getElementById('input1').innerHTML
```

?

Comment: yes , variable declared in global scope  can be use within the function , however that's not the case in input value . I try to append it on window ( window.value1) however that does not work either